# Resident evil Equipment

Tags: movie, video-games, zombie, resident-evil

In the Resident Evil game "Resident Evil 6" and the movie "Resident Evil Damnation", Chris and Leon have two vials on their chest rigs.

**What's in them?**

[image]

Comment: They look suspiciously like the herb vials you get in the game from picking up Green/Yellow/Red Herbs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure those are signal flares (or possibly glowsticks), rather than vials of any particular substance. Admittedly, this is based on having seen these "fanart" images by [JhonyHebert](http://jhonyhebert.deviantart.com/art/Chris-Redfield-And-Piers-Nivans-Resident-Evil-6-330038390).

I'm trying to find a better source, but I can't think what else they could be

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another possibility is adrenaline

Comment: or maybe even *whoop ass.*

Comment: @MajorStackings - I believe that comes in cans.